# How to tune `wilcox.test` in `R` to compare means instead of medians

Tags: r, distributions, inference, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

## My question is: how does one tune `wilcox.test` in `R` to compare means instead of medians?

### Background

[According to this site by Laerd Statistics](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/mann-whitney-u-test-using-spss-statistics.php) one can use a Wilcoxon Rank-Sum / Mann-Whitney U test for determining if there is a statistically significant difference in the center of two continuous distributions. Specifically, the default behavior of the test is to compare the *medians*. However, as described by that site in assumption #4, if the two distributions are not 'similarly-shaped', then the test should instead be tuned so as to compare the *means* instead.

I am on board with all of that.

Now I want to know how to implement these two versions of the test in `R`.

From my reading of the `wilcox.test` documentation ([here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html)), the default behavior is to compare the medians. However, I do not see any parameter which can be used to alter the behavior so that the means are compared instead. I tried to understand if perhaps I could use the parameter `mu` to achieve this, but I think that's a dead end.

#### Example code (if it is helpful)

```
# Build dataset
bwBySmoke <- data.frame(
    `Birth weight` = c(
        2.18, 2.74, 2.9, 2.27, 2.65, 2.42, 2.23, 2.86, 3.6, 3.65, 3.69, 3.53, 2.38, 2.34, 3.99, 3.89, 3.6, 3.73, 3.31, 3.7, 4.08, 3.61, 3.83, 3.41, 4.13, 3.36, 3.54, 3.51, 2.71
        )
    , `Smoking habit` = c(
        'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Heavy smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers', 'Non-smokers'
        )
    )

# View distributions
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)
bwBySmoke %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Smoking.habit, x = Birth.weight)) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = 'binline', bins = 20)

# Do Wilcoxon Rank-Sum / Mann-Whitney U test with default parameters to compare medians
with(bwBySmoke,
    wilcox.test(Birth.weight~Smoking.habit
        ))

# Do Wilcoxon Rank-Sum / Mann-Whitney U test with default parameters to compare means since distributions are not similar with my mystery parameter commented out since I don't think it exists
with(bwBySmoke,
    wilcox.test(Birth.weight~Smoking.habit
        #, mystery_parameter = 'mean'
        ))
```

### If `wilcox.test` cannot be tuned, is there an alternative test to use?

This was originally posted to Stack Overflow, but I was kindly redirected here and I deleted the other post. The person who redirected me indicated that `wilcox.test` will not work for me. I am okay with that, but then is there another function (perhaps from a different library?) that *will* perform a Wilcoxon Rank-Sum / Mann-Whitney U test to compare mean ranks instead of median ranks?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website you linked does not mention anything about tuning the test or about the test is used to compare means. The Mann-Whitney test always tests the differences between mean ranks, which is written on the website, but mean ranks are not the same as means (ranks are first, second, third, etc.). Mann-Whitney test is never comparing median ranks.

You don't need to "tune the test," the website is only talking about the interpretation of the results. If the distributions are the same, then testing the difference between mean ranks equals to testing the difference between medians, therefore you can interpret the results as a test of a difference between medians, otherwise, you cannot. If you want to test the difference in means, you can use a t-test, which has different assumptions.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that I didn't give enough attention to means vs mean ranks and medians vs median ranks and therefore I was a bit confused. Your answer and a re-reading of the Laerd text helped me get clarity.

Answer (score 9):

1. In spite of what the linked page says (and it clearly does at the time of writing*), the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test does not compare medians. If you're looking at pure-shift alternatives, it's measuring the shift by the median of all possible cross-group differences ($x_i-y_j$).

   More generally (outside a pure-shift alternative), the test compares the proportion of times $x_i>y_j$ with the proportion of times $x_i<y_j$, a particular sense of 'tends to be larger'.

   I will say that the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney does quite well, power-wise, when used in exactly the situation the t-test is designed to be 'best' at; you lose very slight amounts of power at that distributional assumption, but gain advantage on shift alternatives when the distribution is a little more heavy-tailed, and that advantage can become large in some situations. At large sample sizes the cost in power at the normal is similar to giving up about 1 observation in every 22; but the possible advantage in power away from the normal may be large. However, if the shapes and or spread don't remain constant under the alternative it's not acting as a test specifically for the difference in mean.
2. You can't really "tune" the test itself. If you change the test statistic, it will no longer be the same test. You can do something that is in some sense similar, however and get a test of means (assuming you want a nonparametric test of means).

   This is straightforward; you can do a permutation test, either of the difference in means or of some standardized form of the difference in means (like the t-statistic itself, for example). A permutation version of a difference of means test will have asymptotic relative efficiency of 1 compared to the t-test at the normal, it will remain a test of means in the same sense that the t-test is when the assumptions don't all hold, but it will maintain control of the type I error rate even in cases where the t-test would not.

   However, it would not outperform the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney on shift alternatives with heavier tails than the normal (at least more than very slightly heavier -- typically as you go to heavier tailed distributions that are not strongly asymmetric the WMW passes both the t-test and this permutation test of means in power pretty quickly, when a sample can still look pretty near normal).
3. If you want a non-parametric test because you think you have some other distribution than the normal, it may pay to consider whether you can reasonably use some other model than the normal. If the distributional model is a good description you may get better power by choosing a test statistic with good power in those circumstances, and the significance level control can still be retained outside it by using a permutation test. In some situations you may end up effectively comparing a ratio of means rather than a difference of means, while still testing equality of means.

---

* Exercise caution when reading random pages on the internet written by people whose expertise you don't have a good way to identify; many people giving stats advice on the internet have much less knowledge than they appear to think (this is not specifically intended as a reference to the page you linked, but as a general warning to be cautious). Here on CrossValidated at least, there's multiple people who do have useful, identifiable expertise who are likely to see and dispute errors, so comments will often clearly identify claims about which some caution may be needed. That constant 'peer review' available here is crucial, I believe, to being able to land *mostly* in the ballpark of good advice.

That's not to say everyone with a good amount of expertise agrees on what the right advice is in a given situation, but the obvious and egregious errors are generally avoided or at least clearly-enough identified. The comments are often a gold mine, and frequently pack a great deal of knowledge into a few well-chosen words. That just doesn't happen on web pages like that, where there's absolutely no indication of what experts might say in response to it.

Comment: An exceptionally good answer Glen.  I want to add a brief note to the permutation test part of the answer.  If severe skewness or heavy tails makes the sample mean not a good choice as a measure of central tendency, the permutation test will not fix that.

Comment: No dispute there; the test statistic can have poor power.