# Function in `R` for inferring if two distributions are similar / not dissimilar?

Tags: r, distributions, inference

## Background

[According to this site by Laerd Statistics](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/mann-whitney-u-test-using-spss-statistics.php) one can use a Wilcoxon Rank-Sum / Mann-Whitney U test for determining if there is a statistically significant difference between the mean ranks of two continuous distributions. However, if assumption #4 on that site is not met, then it alters how one can interpret the results of the test. If the distributions are similar, then one can conclude that the medians are different; if the distributions are not similar, then one can only conclude that the mean ranks are different.

(Note: I posted a related, but different question with a similar background [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546347/how-to-tune-wilcox-test-in-r-to-compare-means-instead-of-medians/546353#546353).)

## The question

How does one formally / objectively assess — in `R` — if two distributions one wants to compare are statistically similar, or at least not dissimilar? In this specific case, one would want to be assured that the distributions are "similar enough" to justify using the default behavior of `wilcox.test`; that is to say, to justify drawing conclusions about medians instead of just mean ranks. However, the question applies for other use cases beyond the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum / Mann-Whitney U test.

I can plot histograms and / or kernel density plots (`ggridges` is great) and do a subjective / eyeball assessment, but is there not a more rigorous method to assess the validity of assumption #4 from the Laerd statistics website?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Using hypothsis tests for checking assumptions is often problematic, you should rather use diagnostic plots and maybe calibrate your interpretation of these plots with some simulations. However, if this is such a strong concern for you, you probably should use a permutation test.

Comment: I think I understand why you say tests for checking assumptions is often problematic --- I presume it's down to inverting how we typically use a null hypothesis in statistical inference. However, at least it's objective and quantifiable. Isn't using diagnostic plots, however, more problematic in that it is all in the eye of the beholder? I like your idea of using simulations and permutations, however.